# Integration Issue of Tango SDK with Cocos2dx 3.0 based game [libpng error: bad parameters to zlib]

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, tango

Atm, I am integrating Tango's SDK with my game, built with Cocos2dx 3.0, and I encountered this issue where XCode's console printed "libpng error: bad parameters to zlib". Initial tracing of the error showed that a function call in CCImage.cpp, png_read_update_info, terminated prematurely when initialising a png file, resulting in a bad excess error when SpriteBatchNode attempts to add a spritesheet to cache as the texture was not initialised successfully. Furthermore, the one of the lib files in the SDK was found to contain a zlib file.

What exactly is the cause of this issue, usage of multiple zlib? Ultimately, is there anyway to solve this issue on my part, or Tango has to do something about their SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You might link your project with a different version of zlib. I think Cocos2dx 3.0 has already configured zlib well, so you might need to check whether there is another zlib in your Tango's SDK.

Try to remove it and test it again.